# Can I have blocking I/O within an asynchronous io_machine?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have a server that's currently using asynchronous IO to (1) accept data from cin and send that input across a UNIX socket and (2) accept data on a UNIX socket, parse that data, and send back a response.

When I'm parsing the data, how can I block the I/O that occurs in the parser (`ParseJSON(data_.data())` in the example below)? It should ask questions and collect answers to those questions via cin before returning `parsed` for the `async_write`; currently, the questions are printed, but the response is sent before the answers are input to cin.

`socket_` is a `stream_protocol::socket` from `boost::asio`, FWIW.

```
void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                 size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        string parsed = ParseJSON(data_.data());
        async_write(socket_,
            buffer(parsed),
            boost::bind(&session::handle_write,
                shared_from_this(),
                placeholders::error));
    }
}

void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        socket_.async_read_some(buffer(data_),
            boost::bind(&session::handle_read,
                shared_from_this(),
                placeholders::error,
                placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
}
```

An abbreviated version of what happens in ParseJSON (Some strings replaced with <> for confidentiality):

```
string ParseJSON(string input)
{
    int status;
    string toWrite;

    JSONNode parsed = libjson::parse(input);
    JSONNode::const_iterator iter = parsed.begin(); 
    json_string node_name = iter -> as_string();

    if (node_name.compare("<>") == 0)   
    {
        cout << "<>" << endl;
        cout << "<>";
        cout.flush();
        cin >> status;

        JSONNode n(JSON_NODE);
        n.push_back(JSONNode("<>","<>"));
        JSONNode c(JSON_NODE);
        c.set_name("args");
        c.push_back(JSONNode("<>",status));
        n.push_back(c);
        toWrite = n.write();
        return toWrite;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you should show the code which handles the input/output in the `ParseJSON` call - if you are using `cin>>` for example, then this will "block" until there is some input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ParseJSON()` does a blocking read from `cin` then it will block which means that `handle_read()` won't execute the `async_write()` until `ParseJSON()` returns.

I think the problem is that `parsed` is a stack variable.  `handle_read()` will most likely return before the data is actually written and `parsed` will be destroyed.  The data passed to `async_write()` needs to be valid until the completion handler (`handle_write`) is called.

If `handle_read()` and and `handle_write()` are member functions you could add a `parsed` member to hold the data.  Alternatively, you could wrap `parsed` in shared_ptr that is bound to `handle_write()` something like this:

```
void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                 size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        string *ps = new string(ParseJSON(data_.data()));
        boost::shared_ptr<string> pParsed(ps);
        async_write(socket_,
            buffer(*pParsed),
            boost::bind(&session::handle_write,
                shared_from_this(),
                pParsed,
                placeholders::error));
    }
}

void handle_write(boost::shared_ptr<string> pParsed, 
                  const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        socket_.async_read_some(buffer(data_),
            boost::bind(&session::handle_read,
                shared_from_this(),
                placeholders::error,
                placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }
}
```

When the completion handler exits, the last reference to the shared_ptr will disappear and `ps` will be destroyed.

Comment: This sounds like the problem... any tips on how to fix it?

Comment: +1 this is the problem, `std::string parsed` has automatic storage duration and will go out of scope shortly after `async_write` returns. The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html) for `async_write` describes how the buffer must remain valid until the completion handler is called.